# Why do we say kinetic time dilation requires velocity, not just speed?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Every formula and every discussion about kinetic time dilation uses Velocity (or we could say relative velocity).  But velocity is a vector with both direction and magnitude.  But it seems to me that an object bouncing back and forth or going around in circles or in any other random direction would have the same kinetic time dilation as if it was moving in a straight line, so only speed is required; not velocity.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand the question. For the simple case of linear motion, time dilation is given by
$$ \Delta t = \frac{\Delta \tau}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
(where $\tau$ is the proper time).
Here, $v^2$ is a number $\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$ and hence we talk only about speed, not velocity?
However, keep in mind that the total time dilation will depends on the possible complex motion of a body (as an integral of $d\tau/(\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}})$ through it's motion). So in that sense it will depend on velocity, not speed (But here indeed it's not about the "orientation" of $\vec{v}$, more about its possible length variations).

Comment: Thank you (I just edited)

Comment: The "length variation" of v that you mention is simply the magnitude, so we are back to speed.  So no answer to my question yet of why the formula specifies a vector quantity of v?

Comment: But in which formula are you seeing explicitly the vector quantity v? Could you provide an example?

Comment: There are v's in both of your formulai above.    But more importantly in any discussion about kinetic time dilation they always say "velocity" and never say "speed".  As far as I understand those are two different (but related) things.